# jQuery mobile page transition CSS

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have website with static pages.
I added one page that use jQuery-mobile with a link button to the home page:

```
<a href="index.htm" id="homebtn" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="home">Home</a>
```

When I press the link button the browser change the URL to the website's home page, but the home page is loaded without the CSS styling! The whole home page looks bad.

When I press the browser's refresh button the page it looks OK.

When I enter to the website to the home page (or any other page) it looks OK.

Any suggestions how to fix this behavior?

Comment: This may have been a one-off case where the browser was unable to load the CSS. Have you seen this behavior multiple times or did it just happen once?

Comment: It happens every time.

Comment: The CSS file is fine, since it is loaded OK when browsing all the other pages.

Comment: Add a `rel="external"` attribute to your anchor. That will prevent jQuery Mobile from loading the home page through AJAX and merge it in its multi-page model, which may be the cause of your CSS issue.

Comment: Thanks, I added rel="external" and it works fine now!